# Postfix Expression Evaluation Troublesome(PEET)

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I have converted my infix into postfix expression, which is

```
3*(4+5)/10-1     into      345+*10/1-
```

How we can read **10** from postfix expression, because string length function reading just **1** instead of **10** and there is also a following case more that

```
3*(4+0)/10-1     into      340+*10/1- how we can differentiate that,
```

is **40** is forty  or four zero and same case with **10** or one zero

I am using turbo c++

Comment: Question is to the point and 100% cleared

Comment: I Think, FailedDev still required Biscuits and Milk. Not able to eat meat

Comment: minjang, has understand the Question

Comment: I am also really surprised , how FailedDev get 5000 point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please place a white space between (or whatever delimiter) numbers.
`3 4 0 + * 10 / 1 -`

Comment: First of All I appreciate, you understand the Question and then respond :-)